# Why async function returns on awaiting for already resolved promise?

Tags: javascript, language-design

Indeed, such behaviour can cause some performance issuses, i.e. additional context switches between 
caller "thread" and "continuation tail" of async function.

```js
async function f() {
  await Promise.resolve("something");
  console.log("f: after await");
  return "somthing_else";
}

function g() {
  const fres = f();
  console.log("g: f returns");
  fres.then((x) => console.log("finish"));
}

g();
```

The output is (at least in my Chrome):

```
g: f returns
f: after await
finish
```

Since await operator actually has nothing to wait, I would expect:

```
f: after await
g: f returns
finish
```

Is that behaviour specified by standard or it is implementation dependent?

If it is standard behaviour what is the reason?

Comment: AFAIK it's like using setTimeout with a delay of 0. It still ends in the next "cycle" if you will, and doesn't get executed until after the current function finishes.

Comment: Promise callbacks are, by the specification, invoked in a special context. The `async` / `await` facility does not change that. Thus code that relies on the Promise being completed cannot run until after `g()` is completely finished.

Comment: @Pointy probably you comment should be an answer

Comment: @user396672 I was looking for a duplicate because I'm pretty sure there was an extremely similar question just a couple months ago

Answer (score 1):

`f` function is async, so you should await for it within `g` function

```
async function g(){
  const fres = await f();
  console.log("g: f returns");
  fres.then((x) => console.log("finish"));
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, OP expects the function to behave like a non-async one if it resolves immediately and asks why it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Promises are placed in a queue that is executed after the current normal script queue is empty.

So you will finish running g() and hence, push `console.log("g: f returns");` to the current stack before f() resolves.

If the log was inside the `fres.then()` function, it would only be logged after `f()` resolves.